# PHP check if array value is unique

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I was working on something earlier today and I've stumbled upon this problem. How do you check if a certain array value is unique within that array?

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5);

if(unique_in_array($array, 1)) //true
if(unique_in_array($array, 3)) //false
```

I've been thinking about using [array_search()](http://php.net/array_search) or [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array), but neither are very usefull for finding duplicates. I'm sure I could write a function like this to do it:

```
function unique_in_array($arr, $search){
    $found = 0;

    foreach($arr as $val){
        if($search == $val){
            $found++;
        }
    }

    if($found > 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or another solution was to use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/array_count_values) like this:

```
$array_val_count = array_count_values($array);

if($array_val_count[$search] > 1){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But it seems odd to me that PHP has no build in function (or at least a better way) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (1 === count(array_keys($values, $value))) {
    // $value is unique in array
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Awesome! This is actually the most elegant solution so far!

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a few more mins but I think this is by far the best solution. If nothing better pops up, I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can try like this -

```
$array1   = array(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5);

$func   = array_count_values($array1);
$count  = $func[3];  #Pass value here

echo $count;  #this will echo 4

#If you pass undefined value, You should use like as below
$count = isset($func[8])? $func[8] : 0;

echo $count;  #this will echo 0, Because 8 is absent in $array1
```

Here is the function reference of [array_count_values()](http://php.net/array_count_values)

Comment: This is not very helpfull. You're checking if the array has duplicates or not. The question was to check if a certain _value_ is unique or not.

Comment: Ahh! Yes! I am updating my answer! @icecub

Comment: Yes this is what I had in my question as well. I know it works, but I was looking for a more elegant solution like localheinz provided. I'll give you a +1 for efford though. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! +1 @icecub

Comment: But in this solution, if `echo == 1`, That mean Value is unique in the array. @icecub

Comment: Yes I know. But instead of simply going through the array once, you're creating another array out of the first one and start comparing the value. It's a lot of overhead that isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to check if array has duplicate values

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5);

if(count(array_unique($array)) != count($array)){
    // Return true Array is unique
}
else{
    // Return false Array is not unique
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but please read the question again. The question was if a specific value in an array is unique. Not if the entire array has unique values. So in an array like `[0, 0, 1, 2, 2]` it should return true for checking out `1` and false for all the others. @FedericoBaù This question is really old (3 / 4 years) and answered a long time ago. I honestly couldn't even remember asking it.